# Understanding the process behind finding a sum to an infinite series

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling to understand why the sum of $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (e^{1/n}-e^{1/{n+1}})$$
is equivalent to/converges to $$e-1$$

I'm also unsure of the process to cancel terms to yield $$s_n=e-e^{1/{n+1}}$$

I would like to understand these concepts clearly, so detailed answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: As a side remark: It is better to write $1/(n+1)$ instead of $1/n + 1$, since the latter could equally be read as $(1/n) + 1$ (which is actually how I would read it).

Use parentheses! Seriously! They're there for a reason!

Answer (score 2):

It's a [Telescoping Sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{1/i}-e^{1/(i+1)}=s_n$$

$$\begin{align}
s_n&=(e^{1}-e^{1/2})+(e^{1/2}-e^{1/3})+\cdots+(e^{1/(n-1)}-e^{1/n})+(e^{1/n}-e^{1/(n+1)})\\
&=e^{1}+(-e^{1/2}+e^{1/2})+(-e^{1/3}+e^{1/3})\cdots+(-e^{1/n}+e^{1/n})-e^{1/(n+1)}\\
&=e+0+0+0+\cdots+0-e^{1/(n+1)}\\
s_n&=e-e^{(n+1)}
\end{align}$$

Infinite sum can also be written as
$$\begin{align}
s&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n e^{1/i}-e^{1/(i+1)}\right)\\
s&=\lim_{n \to \infty} e-e^{1/(n+1)}=e-1\\
\end{align}$$
$$\Rightarrow s=e-1$$

Comment: This is called *telescoping*.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right trace.

The sum is $\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(e-e^{\frac{1}{n+1}})=e-e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n+1})}=e-e^0=e-1$

Comment: How did you obtain the term e - e^(1/n+1) in that second part of this equation of yours... In other words where did the 1/n in the power of e go from the original equation I put up?